# Why caching small Spark RDDs takes big memory allocation in Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

The RDDs that are cached (in total 8) are not big, only around **30G**, however, on Hadoop UI, it shows that the Spark application is taking lots of memory (no active jobs are running), i.e. **1.4T**, why so much?

[image]

[image]

Why it shows around 100 executors (here, i.e. vCores) even when there's no active jobs running?

Also, if cached RDDs are stored across 100 executors, are those executors preserved and no more other Spark apps can use them for running tasks any more? To rephrase the question: will preserving a little memory resource (`.cache`) in executors prevents other Spark app from leveraging the idle computing resource of them?

Is there any potential Spark config / zeppelin config that can cause this phenomenon?

---

**UPDATE 1**

After checking the Spark conf (zeppelin), it seems there's the default (configured by administrator by default) setting for `spark.executor.memory=10G`, which is probably the reason why.

However, here's a new question: Is it possible to keep only the memory needed for the cached RDDs in each executors and release the rest, instead of holding always the initially set memory `spark.executor.memory=10G`?

Spark configuration

[image]

Comment: The memory consumption can be due to many things - cached RDDs are only part of it. If you want to reduce memory usage, you could try setting `spark.executor.memory` to a lower value

Comment: @mck Thanks. What else can take the memory up to 1.4T if no jobs are running AND cached RDDs are so small?

Comment: previous running jobs can have some uncollected garbage

Comment: @mck True, that's inspiring hints, shouldn't Spark does the GC automatically, or is there a way to trigger the GC by users? I suppose this should be a common problem, and it's severe as it's occupying so much resource after running app..

Comment: I'm not sure, from my experience it tends to collect garbage when it's running out  of memory. If you give it 1T it will just use it all until it runs out of space.

Comment: In my case seems not, other Spark apps are just blocked due to that, they are waiting for my app to release resource by - manually killing it.. Who should we blame for? My Spark app config or Yarn, or Hadoop? Who is taking care of this aspect?

Comment: I suppose the config is to blame. I presume the config is 1T memory, so every spark app thought they have 1T to use, but in reality they're sharing the 1T, which makes them struggle. Perhaps it's better to specify 100G for each app, if you need to run multiple apps

Comment: @mck I set no specific conf for `spark.executor.memory` and i assume the app will take up to whatever size memory it needs, which is fine for the cluster (as we do have that resource), but when finishing, I'd like it to release the occupied resource that **was** used. So I do not want to restrict `spark.executor.memory` as it makes no sense to restrict if it needs when running jobs, but releasing after it finishes - that's absolutely desired. Really want to know how to achieve..

Comment: how about calling spark.stop after you app finishes...?

Comment: I would need the `cache`d RDDs for interactive analytics, that's why i `cache` so as to avoid recomputing. But i'd like Spark to keep only the memory used for caching after it finishes computing and let all others go, not being greedy - which i guess is something Spark should be capable of handling, no?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but that certainly sounds like the ideal case :)

Comment: @jack can you share config.

Comment: @Chandan Just added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to `repartition(n)` your RDD to a fewer `n < 100` partitions before caching. A ~30GB RDD would probably fit into storage memory of ten 10GB executors. A good overview of Spark memory management can be found [here](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/).  This way, only those executors that hold cached blocks will be "pinned" to your application, while the rest can be reclaimed by YARN via Spark dynamic allocation after `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout` (default 60s).

*Q: Is it possible to keep only the memory needed for the cached RDDs in each executors and release the rest, instead of holding always the    initially set memory spark.executor.memory=10G?*

When Spark uses YARN as its execution engine, YARN allocates the containers of a specified (by application) size -- at least `spark.executor.memory+spark.executor.memoryOverhead`, but may be even bigger in case of pyspark -- for all the executors. How much memory Spark actually uses *inside* a container becomes irrelevant, since the resources allocated to a container will be considered off-limits to other YARN applications.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried `df.repartitionByRange(4, col("key"))`, and then trigger an action, but I still see that "Data Distribution on 100 Executors" in "Storage" UI, and Yarn still shows 101 executors, any idea why it failed to repartition?

Comment: Are you sure your action is caching repartitioned dataset, not repartitioning cached dataset? The order is important... :)

Comment: I `unpersist` the cached df/rdd, `repartition` the df/rdd and `cache` and trigger action again, then it does reduce the nb. of executors occupied. A better solution might be to use `coalesce` as it should avoid unnecessary shuffling IMO.

Comment: Sometimes, even after `repartition` is used and that only 1 executor is holding the cached item, there're still 20 executors that are in `ALIVE` state doing nothing! Should I explicitly kill them? Why Spark is not recycling them? Is this expected?

Comment: @jack, the executors are alive because the action is flagged as completed when all tasks have finished. So if one task has more data, the others will be just waiting for it to finish. That's why it's important to redistribute the data in some way. Even with dynamic allocation enabled, tasks are not going to be sent to other actions, so the only choice here is to set data evenly distributed

Comment: @jack that doesn't sound right, normally you should see the number of executors going down to `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` (after idle timeout). So, something else is going on, and you would probably need to look at the driver log to see why it doesn't command them to shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Spark assumes that your **data is equally distributed on all the executors and tasks**. That's the reason why you set memory per task. So to make Spark to consume less memory, your data has to be evenly distributed:

- If you are reading from Parquet files or CSVs, make sure that they have similar sizes. Running `repartition()` causes shuffling, which if the data is so skewed may cause other problems if executors don't have enough resources
- Cache won't help to release memory on the executors because it doesn't redistribute the data
- Can you please see under "Event Timeline" on the Stages "how big are the green bars?" Normally that's tied to the data distribution, so that's a way to see how much data is loaded (proportionally) on every task and how much they are doing. As all tasks have same memory assigned, you can see graphically if resources are wasted (in case there are mostly tiny bars and few big bars). A sample of wasted resources can be seen on the image below

[image]

There are different ways to create evenly distributed files for your process. I mention some possibilities, but for sure there are more:

- Using Hive and `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause: you need to use a field that is equally balanced in order to create as many files (and with proper size) as expected
- If the process creating those files is a Spark process reading from a DB, try to create as many connections as files you need and use a proper field to populate Spark partitions. That is achieved, as explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) and [here](https://jozef.io/r926-spark-jdbc-partitioning/) with partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound and numPartitions properties
- Repartition may work, but see if coalesce also make sense in your process or in the previous one generating the files you are reading from

Comment: @jack, that's no problem. See if you can redistribute your data in any way so that you can lower down memory requirements on executors

Comment: See my comment in [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495603/8932910) about executors being `ALIVE`, any idea on that?

Comment: replied above, as this is where the comment is :). Thank you for pointing me there!